# How to convert a list into a dictionary object and return from function?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Sample code below:

```
list_of_dict = list([{'id':1,'amt':1},{'id':2,'amt':20},{'id':3,'amt':30}])

def fooFunc(a,b):
    rows = []                       ## list object
    for e in range(b):
        new = a.copy()
        new['amt']  = a['amt'] / b
        rows.append(new)            ## using append()
    return rows

output=[]
for i in list_of_dict:
    idnmbr = i['id']
    if idnmbr == 2:
        output.append(fooFunc(i,2))
    elif idnmbr == 3:
        output.append(fooFunc(i,3))
    else:
        output.append(i)

print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'id': 1, 'amt': 1}, [{'id': 2, 'amt': 10.0}, {'id': 2, 'amt': 10.0}], [{'id': 3, 'amt': 10.0}, {'id': 3, 'amt': 10.0}, {'id': 3, 'amt': 10.0}]]
```

Wan't to get rid of [square brackets] i.e. [{'id': 2, 'amt': 10.0}, {'id': 2, 'amt': 10.0}]
that is being appended from the function call that returns results/rows as a list.

Tried converting the function call return to a dictionary object, but results are not as expected.

```
def fooFuncDict(a,b):
    rows = {}                 ## dictionary object
    for e in range(b):
        new = a.copy()
        new['amt']  = a['amt'] / b
        rows.update(new)      ## using update()
    return rows

output=[]
for i in list_of_dict:
    idnmbr = i['id']
    if idnmbr == 2:
        output.append(fooFuncDict(i,2))
    elif idnmbr == 3:
        output.append(fooFuncDict(i,3))
    else:
        output.append(i)

print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'id': 1, 'amt': 1}, {'id': 2, 'amt': 10.0}, {'id': 3, 'amt': 10.0}]
```

Comment: What would your expected output be? How would you return a sequence of dictionaries in an object that is not a list?

Comment: Expected output is to have data like this (without square brackets within the list i.e. lists within a list) : -  [{'id': 1, 'amt': 1}, {'id': 2, 'amt': 10.0}, {'id': 2, 'amt': 10.0}, {'id': 3, 'amt': 10.0}, {'id': 3, 'amt': 10.0}, {'id': 3, 'amt': 10.0}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need `list.extend`

**Ex:**

```
output=[]
for i in list_of_dict:
    idnmbr = i['id']
    if idnmbr == 1:
        output.append(i)
    else:
        output.extend(fooFunc(i,idnmbr))

print(output)
# [{'id': 1, 'amt': 1}, {'id': 2, 'amt': 10.0}, {'id': 2, 'amt': 10.0}, {'id': 3, 'amt': 10.0}, {'id': 3, 'amt': 10.0}, {'id': 3, 'amt': 10.0}]
```